# React Native: Fit Text's content inside View without specific size

Tags: react-native

I have an **Image** and a **Text** component inside a **Container** with flex-direction row that fits 100% of my screen. The Text component has no size specified to it, neither does the Container.

When I have a single word that is to big, the Text component cuts the end of it's content with "-"; When I have a bunch of small words, the Text component cuts it's content after a given word; When I have a single small word (my use case) the Text component cuts the end of the word in a random character, **even though** it has plenty of space to render the text.

Here are my code snippets:

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import { Container, Top, Logo, Title } from './styles';

import logo from '../../assets/Nubank_Logo.png';

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Top>
        <Logo source={logo} />
        <Title>Bruno</Title>
      </Top>
      <Icon name="keyboard-arrow-down" size={20} color="#fff" />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const Container = styled.View`
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px 0 30px 0;
`;

export const Top = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

export const Logo = styled.Image``;

export const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 8px;
`;
```

[And here is an screenshot of the result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNuW2.png)

Comment: Do you want to show the text without word-wrap?

Comment: Yes, without word wrapping. It actually shouldn't be cutting, since it has plenty of space left.

Comment: Maybe it's not actually what you seen, it's suggested that you set border to see the real box/margin, then choose the correct method.

Comment: I just posted a solution to this problem down below, will close this question since I don't need help anymore. Thank you so much for replying <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the cause to my problem.

I have a OnePlus 6 phone with android 9. I was using **OnePlus Slate** as my phone's default font.

The problem is that React Native Text component cuts the end of the text **depending on the font you are using**. It's a bug that has been around for a while and they still didn't find a solution for it. Here are some issues on their page on github:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17026
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17629

and the comment in which I found the solution:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114#issuecomment-520112872

**My solution**

Since my phone has the option to change the system font family I just went and changed it to Roboto, as a test. In a real scenario you would need to change your app's default font family to Roboto.